# JUnit Test: How to test for nested Exeption?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to write JUnit Test to test for the following code snippet. Using Mockito, I was able to mock and test for the first Exception. Is it possible to use Mockito or any relevant library to test for nested Exception if I would not like to change the implementation?

The following is the code that I would like to write unit test for:

```
...
    else {
         response.sendRedirect("path to error URL");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
         logger.error(ex.getMessage());
         try {
              response.sendRedirect("path to error URL");
         }catch(IOException e) {                     <= Unable to test for the following Exception
              logger.error(ex.getMessage());
         }
}
```

I have looked up various solutions online such as writing two mockito when statements but has not been successful. I would greatly appreciate any form of help or sharing of knowledge if you have encountered the following issue previously. Thank you!

Comment: can you show the code test method code ?

Comment: Are you referring to the JUnit test code that I have tried out previously but was not successful?

Comment: yes exactly @Richard

Comment: Another work around could be if you can move the inner try catch code to a different method and call that method explicitly from your JUNIT as another test case.

Comment: when(class.method()).thenThrow(NullPointerException.class);
when(class.method().response.sendRedirect("path to error URL");).thenThrow(IOException.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stub the different response for [consecutive calls](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10)

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).doThrow(new EOFException()).when(mock).sendRedirect("some url"); // for first and inner catch block
```

In case if you have two different `URL` you can have individual stubs

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).sendRedirect("first url") // for first catch block
doThrow(new EOFException()).when(mock).sendRedirect("second url") // for inner catch block
```